# Does the "iter" parameter of gensim.models.Word2Vec method iterate over the whole corpus or the sentence passed to it at a time?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am using gensim to train a word2Vec model. Here I am passing one sentence at a time to the gensim.models.Word2Vec() method from my corpus to gradually train the model on my whole corpus. But I am confused what should the value of iter parameter be as I'm not sure whether it iterates over the passed sentence n times or the whole corpus.

I have tried checking the documentation of gensim. it states the definition as follows:

> iter (int, optional) – Number of iterations (epochs) over the corpus.

But I am confused as I am not passing the whole corpus but only a single sentence on each iteration.

My line in the code that trains the model looks like this:
`model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(data, min_count=2, window=arg.window_size, size=arg.dim_size, workers=4, sg=0, hs=0, negative=10, ns_exponent=0.75, alpha=0.025, iter=1)`

Here "data" represents a single sentence passed at a time from a generator.

Suppose I have a corpus of 2 sentences. "X is a variable. Y is a variable too.". The model receives data = "X is a variable." first and data = "Y is a variable too." in 2nd iteration. 
Now to clarify, my question is, **whether iter = 50 will train my model iterating though "X is a variable." 50 times & "Y is a variable too." 50 times or will it iterating though "X is a variable. Y is a variable too." (my whole corpus) 50 times.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Word2Vec` is a class. Calling it as `model = Word2Vec(...)` returns one new model instance.

If you supply data to that instantiation call, it expects a full training corpus, with all examples, as the data (`sentences` parameter). It will iterate over that data once to learn the vocabulary, then again the number of times specified in the `epochs` argument for training. (This argument was previously called `iter`, which still works.)

So:

- You shouldn't be calling `Word2Vec(...)` multiple times with single texts. You should call it once, with a re-iterable sequence of all your texts as the data.
- That full supplied corpus will be iterated over `epochs` + 1 times as part of the model's initialization & training, via the single call to `Word2Vec(...)`.

You should enable logging at the INFO level to get a better idea of what's happening when you try different approaches.

You should also look at working examples, like the `word2vec.ipynb` notebook bundled with `gensim` inside its `docs/notebooks` directory, to understand usual usage patterns. (This is best viewed, and interactively run, from your local installation – but can also be browsed online at https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/word2vec.ipynb.)

Note that you **can** avoid supplying any data to the `Word2Vec(...)` instantiation call, but then you need to call `model.build_vocab(full_corpus)` and then `model.train(full_corpus, epochs=desired_iterations)` to complete the model initialization & training. (While you can then continue calling `train()` with fragments of training data, that's an advanced & highly error-prone approach. Only calling it just once, with one combined full training set, will easily and automatically do the right thing with the training learning-rate decay and number of training iterations.)